# Is there a way to access a google drive folder if i have a link to one file in it?

Tags: google-drive, cloud-storage

I accidentally copied the wrong link to very important folder. I copied a link to one of the files instead of the whole folder. Is there a way to get the link to whole folder if the only thing i have is one of the files, and i don't have the google account anymore(it's in the database in this folder).

Answer (score 2):

It would be astonishingly poor security if anyone could do that. No, the links are randomly generated precisely to prevent this.

Example links, to a folder & the two files it contains. There is no correlation between the names, & the apparent folder structures `folder` or  `file/d/` cannot be accessed directly by anyone.  [The files no longer exist in these locations, this is just for example.]

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16NGecjINcr8jH4p_yrH71qdIAUK1aFCH?usp=share_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ztrrs_NuucNbbNQjDqtYEK3Cg4JX6kM4/view?usp=share_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OaYmpfpnhu7fcdV0Y-bvtySVtgzyiN3c/view?usp=share_link
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too long ago, Google Drive allowed files and folders to have multiple parents. It was relatively easy to get the parent(s) folder(s) of a file if the user had the appropriate authorization / the file and folder had the appropriate, in this case convenient, sharing settings.

Depending on the file type, you might click the link and look at the file information and details. If the parent folder is shared with you instead of with anyone with the link/on the web, you should be able to see the folder. It might be easier to see by searching for the file using Google Drive, selecting the files and looking at the details panels, the toolbar and the contextual (right-click) menu. Your mileage might vary depending on the type of Google account the edition. If you are an admin or super admin, you might have more features if the file belongs to the organization / domain that you manage.

If the folder is shared with anyone with the link / on the web or using a Google Group and you have never accessed it, it might not be shown.

You might try to use the Google Drive Service, Advanced Google Drive on Google Apps Script. Also, you might try to use the Google Drive API with your favorite programming language capable of handling OAuth and REST requests.